# ASP.NET sites unintentionally sharing login cookie

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies

I have a few ASP.NET sites running on one IIS server, of course using different ports. The sites allow for logging in via forms authentication. Session state is stored on a local state server. My problem is that when a user logs into one sites and then navigates to another, they get an exception from the second site and have to close/reopen their web browser to be able to access it. My guess is that the cookie from the first site is making it appear that they're logged in on the second one as well (though I could be completely wrong about this).

I've tried a few things to fix it (which are probably dumb and have nothing to do with the problem, but I'm far from an ASP.NET expert) including:
1) giving the sites different cookie names in Web.config's sessionState tag, and
2) Moving the sites to different app pools, but the problem persists. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend setting up different domains for each site.  If this is local, use the host file to route local.site1.com and local.site2.com to the correct place.  Obviously you'll have to keep the port.  Then you should be setting cookie with a different domain for each site and not causing the confusion.

Comment: That's a great idea, but it's problematic here because we don't have any other servers with multiple domains, and our infrastructure team is hesitant to have this server be the only one (since if something happened during off hours, the helpdesk employees might not understand the configuration). This is an internal server on our intranet, and we're using WINS, so *.server doesn't automatically resolve to the server.

Comment: In that case it seems like you are going to have to write an httpmodule that will check the cookie for some custom data that will dependently delete / expire the cookie from the request and then write the appropriate data back in the response.  For instance, perhaps write the app name to the user data in every app on every response, then in each application check the request for this data and take appropriate action on the forms auth cookie.  It is a hacky bad solution, but not sure what else to do.